# Algorithm for expanding a character set?

Tags: c#

Are there any ready-made functions for expanding a C# regex-style character set?

For example, `expand("a-z1")` would return a string containing all the characters a to z, followed by the number 1.

---

Here's what I've got so far:

```
public static string ExpandCharacterSet(string set)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    int start = 0;
    while (start < set.Length - 1)
    {
        int dash = set.IndexOf('-', start + 1);

        if (dash <= 0 || dash >= set.Length - 1)
            break;

        sb.Append(set.Substring(start, dash - start - 1));

        char a = set[dash - 1];
        char z = set[dash + 1];

        for (var i = a; i <= z; ++i)
            sb.Append(i);

        start = dash + 2;
    }

    sb.Append(set.Substring(start));
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Is there anything I'm overlooking?

**PS:** Let's ignore negative character sets for now.

---

Thought my example was quite clear... let's try that again. This is what I want:

```
ExpandCharacterSet("a-fA-F0-9") == "abcdefABCDEF0123456789"
```

Comment: Are you asking how to input a regex character class, (`[a-fA-F0-9]`), and output all characters described by the class (`abcdefABCDEF0123456789`)?

Comment: @Seth: Yes. Square brackets optional.

Comment: Ah sorry Mark, misinterpreted your question.  There isn't a builtin way to expand it AFAIK.  I'll have to refine my answer.

Comment: Are you looking for a robust implementation or will you assume simple character ranges?  e.g., no escapes, well formed inputs, etc.

Comment: @Jeff: Robust, unfortunately. We can assume it's well-formed, but escapes and everything else are fair game.

Comment: Man, if we had access to the .NET regex parser, this would be trivial.  Everything is marked internal unfortunately.  There ought to be a way to circumvent that which I'm exploring right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static readonly IEnumerable<char> CharacterSet = Enumerable.Range(0, char.MaxValue + 1).Select(Convert.ToChar).Where(c => !char.IsControl(c));

public static string ExpandCharacterSet(string set)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    int start = 0;
    bool invertSet = false;

    if (set.Length == 0) 
        return "";
    if (set[0] == '[' && set[set.Length - 1] == ']')
        set = set.Substring(1, set.Length - 2);
    if (set[0] == '^')
    {
        invertSet = true;
        set = set.Substring(1);
    }

    while (start < set.Length - 1)
    {
        int dash = set.IndexOf('-', start + 1);

        if (dash <= 0 || dash >= set.Length - 1)
            break;

        sb.Append(set.Substring(start, dash - start - 1));

        char a = set[dash - 1];
        char z = set[dash + 1];

        for (var i = a; i <= z; ++i)
            sb.Append(i);

        start = dash + 2;
    }

    sb.Append(set.Substring(start));

    if (!invertSet) return sb.ToString();

    var A = new HashSet<char>(CharacterSet);
    var B = new HashSet<char>(sb.ToString());
    A.ExceptWith(B);
    return new string(A.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: I think this can produce duplicate letters if they appear twice in the character set, but otherwise this should work.

Answer (score 2):

It took a bit of work to get this but here's what I was able to muster.  Of course this is not going to be portable since I'm messing with internals.  But it works well enough for simple test cases.  It will accept any regex character class but will not work for negated classes.  The range of values is way too broad without any restrictions.  I don't know if it will be correct for all cases and it doesn't handle repetition at all but it's a start.  At least you won't have to roll out your own parser.  As of .NET Framework 4.0:

```
public static class RegexHelper
{
    public static string ExpandCharClass(string charClass)
    {
        var regexParser = new RegexParser(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        regexParser.SetPattern(charClass);
        var regexCharClass = regexParser.ScanCharClass(false);
        int count = regexCharClass.RangeCount();
        List<string> ranges = new List<string>();
        // range 0 can be skipped
        for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
        {
            var range = regexCharClass.GetRangeAt(i);
            ranges.Add(ExpandRange(range));
        }
        return String.Concat(ranges);
    }

    static string ExpandRange(SingleRange range)
    {
        char first = range._first;
        char last = range._last;
        return String.Concat(Enumerable.Range(first, last - first + 1).Select(i => (char)i));
    }

    internal class RegexParser
    {
        static readonly Type RegexParserType;
        static readonly ConstructorInfo RegexParser_Ctor;
        static readonly MethodInfo RegexParser_SetPattern;
        static readonly MethodInfo RegexParser_ScanCharClass;

        static RegexParser()
        {
            RegexParserType = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Regex)).GetType("System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser");

            var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
            RegexParser_Ctor = RegexParserType.GetConstructor(flags, null, new[] { typeof(CultureInfo) }, null);
            RegexParser_SetPattern = RegexParserType.GetMethod("SetPattern", flags, null, new[] { typeof(String) }, null);
            RegexParser_ScanCharClass = RegexParserType.GetMethod("ScanCharClass", flags, null, new[] { typeof(Boolean) }, null);
        }

        private readonly object instance;

        internal RegexParser(CultureInfo culture)
        {
            instance = RegexParser_Ctor.Invoke(new object[] { culture });
        }

        internal void SetPattern(string pattern)
        {
            RegexParser_SetPattern.Invoke(instance, new object[] { pattern });
        }

        internal RegexCharClass ScanCharClass(bool caseInsensitive)
        {
            return new RegexCharClass(RegexParser_ScanCharClass.Invoke(instance, new object[] { caseInsensitive }));
        }
    }

    internal class RegexCharClass
    {
        static readonly Type RegexCharClassType;
        static readonly MethodInfo RegexCharClass_RangeCount;
        static readonly MethodInfo RegexCharClass_GetRangeAt;

        static RegexCharClass()
        {
            RegexCharClassType = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Regex)).GetType("System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexCharClass");

            var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
            RegexCharClass_RangeCount = RegexCharClassType.GetMethod("RangeCount", flags, null, new Type[] { }, null);
            RegexCharClass_GetRangeAt = RegexCharClassType.GetMethod("GetRangeAt", flags, null, new[] { typeof(Int32) }, null);
        }

        private readonly object instance;

        internal RegexCharClass(object regexCharClass)
        {
            if (regexCharClass == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("regexCharClass");
            if (regexCharClass.GetType() != RegexCharClassType)
                throw new ArgumentException("not an instance of a RegexCharClass object", "regexCharClass");
            instance = regexCharClass;
        }

        internal int RangeCount()
        {
            return (int)RegexCharClass_RangeCount.Invoke(instance, new object[] { });
        }

        internal SingleRange GetRangeAt(int i)
        {
            return new SingleRange(RegexCharClass_GetRangeAt.Invoke(instance, new object[] { i }));
        }
    }

    internal struct SingleRange
    {
        static readonly Type RegexCharClassSingleRangeType;
        static readonly FieldInfo SingleRange_first;
        static readonly FieldInfo SingleRange_last;

        static SingleRange()
        {
            RegexCharClassSingleRangeType = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Regex)).GetType("System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexCharClass+SingleRange");

            var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
            SingleRange_first = RegexCharClassSingleRangeType.GetField("_first", flags);
            SingleRange_last = RegexCharClassSingleRangeType.GetField("_last", flags);
        }

        internal char _first;
        internal char _last;

        internal SingleRange(object singleRange)
        {
            if (singleRange == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("singleRange");
            if (singleRange.GetType() != RegexCharClassSingleRangeType)
                throw new ArgumentException("not an instance of a SingleRange object", "singleRange");
            _first = (char)SingleRange_first.GetValue(singleRange);
            _last = (char)SingleRange_last.GetValue(singleRange);
        }
    }
}

// usage:
RegexHelper.ExpandCharClass(@"[\-a-zA-F1 5-9]");
// "-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEF1 56789"
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a pretty unusual requirement, but since there are only about 96 characters that you can match (unless you include high chars), you might as well just test your regular expression against all of them, and output the matches:

```
public static string expando(string input_re) {

    // add more chars in s as needed, such as ,.?/|=+_-éñ etc.
    string s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    string output = "";

    Regex exp = new Regex(input_re);

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) {
        if (exp.IsMatch(s.Substring(i, 1))) {
            output += s[i];
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

By using an actual regex to determine your character class, you can expand whatever regular expression you want, `[^A-B]|[0123a-cg-h]`, for example.

Comment: Umm...... where'd you get 96 chars from? We live in a world of unicode :) Things like `\u2000-\u4000` are valid character ranges too. I want it to be *completely* compatible with how Regex processes them.

Comment: (However, I am presently using an approach similar to yours...but I'm looking for something more robust)

Comment: 96 is roughly 128 (ASCII) - 32 (ctrl chars), which are 99% of every Regex I've ever written. . If you want all of unicode, you'll need a bigger string. Actually, in that case you may be better off generating the characters instead of looping over a big string constant.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var input = "a-fA-F0-9!";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input,@".-.|.");

var list = new StringBuilder();

foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    var value = m.Value;

    if (value.Length == 1)
        list.Append(value);
    else
    {
        if (value[2] < value[0]) throw new ArgumentException("invalid format"); // or switch, if you want.
        for (char c = value[0]; c <= value[2]; c++)
            list.Append(c);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(list);
```

Output:

```
abcdefABCDEF0123456789!
```

The moral, of course, is to solve your regex problems with more regex!

---

Here's a version with support for escape characters. It all depends how robust you want it to be... for example, I don't do anything special here to handle surrogates, so that probably won't work. Also, if you're trying to match the performance of a current regex engine exactly you'll need to know exactly what all the parameters are, which would be a fairly big job.

```
void Main()
{
        //these are all equivalent:
        var input = @"\x41-\0x46\u41";
        var input2 = @"\65-\70\65";
        var input3 = "A-FA";

        // match hex as \0x123 or \x123 or \u123, or decimal \412, or the escapes \n\t\r, or any character
        var charRegex = @"(\\(0?x|u)[0-9a-fA-F]+|\\[0-9]+|\\[ntr]|.)";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(input, charRegex + "-" + charRegex + "|" + charRegex);

        var list = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Match m in matches)
        {
            var dashIndex = m.Value.IndexOf('-', 1); //don't look at 0 (in case it's a dash)
            if (dashIndex > 0) // this means we have two items: a range
            {   
                var charLeft = Decode(m.Value.Substring(0,dashIndex));
                var charRight = Decode(m.Value.Substring(dashIndex+1));
                if (charRight < charLeft) throw new ArgumentException("invalid format (left bigger than right)"); // or switch, if you want.
                for (char c = charLeft; c <= charRight; c++)
                    list.Append(c);
            }
            else // just one item
            {
                list.Append(Decode(m.Value));
            }   
        }

        Console.WriteLine(list);
}

char Decode(string s)
{
    if (s.Length == 1)
        return s[0];

    // here, s[0] == '\', because of the regex
    if (s.Length == 2)
        switch (s[1])
        {
        // incomplete; add more as wished
        case 'n': return '\n';
        case 't': return '\t';
        case 'r': return '\r';
        default: break;
        }

    if (s[1] == 'u' || s[1] == 'x')
        return (char)Convert.ToUInt16(s.Substring(2), 16);
    else if (s.Length > 2 && s[1] == '0' && s[2] == 'x')
        return (char)Convert.ToUInt16(s.Substring(3), 16);
    else
        return (char)Convert.ToUInt16(s.Substring(1)); // will fail from here if invalid escape (e.g. \g)
}
```